# Scala - best API for doing work inside multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, scala, multiprocessing

In Python, I am using a library called `futures`, which allows me to do my processing work with a pool of N worker processes, in a succinct and crystal-clear way:

```py
schedulerQ = []
for ... in ...:
    workParam = ...  # arguments for call to processingFunction(workParam)
    schedulerQ.append(workParam)
with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:  # 5 CPUs
    for retValue in executor.map(processingFunction, schedulerQ):
        print "Received result", retValue
```

*(The `processingFunction` is CPU bound, so there is no point for async machinery here - this is about plain old arithmetic calculations)*

I am now looking for the closest possible way to do the same thing in Scala. Notice that in Python, to avoid the GIL issues, I was using processes (hence the use of `ProcessPoolExecutor` instead of `ThreadPoolExecutor`) - and the library automagically marshals the `workParam` argument to each process instance executing `processingFunction(workParam)` - and it marshals the result back to the main process, for the executor's `map` loop to consume.

Does this apply to Scala and the JVM? My processingFunction can, in principle, be executed from threads too (there's no global state at all) - but I'd be interested to see solutions for both multiprocessing and multithreading.

The key part of the question is whether there is anything in the world of the JVM with as clear an API as the Python `futures` you see above... I think this is one of the best SMP APIs I've ever seen - prepare a list with the function arguments of all invocations, and then just two lines: create the poolExecutor, and `map` the processing function, getting back your results as soon as they are produced by the workers. Results start coming in as soon as the first invocation of `processingFunction` returns and keep coming until they are all done - at which point the for loop ends.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have way less boilerplate than that using parallel collections in Scala.

```
myParameters.par.map(x => f(x))
```

will do the trick if you want the default number of threads (same as number of cores).

If you insist on setting the number of workers, you can like so:

```
import scala.collection.parallel._
import scala.concurrent.forkjoin._

val temp = myParameters.par
temp.tasksupport = new ForkJoinTaskSupport(new ForkJoinPool(5))
temp.map(x => f(x))
```

The exact details of return timing are different, but you can put as much machinery as you want into `f(x)` (i.e. both compute and do something with the result), so this may satisfy your needs.

In general, simply having the results appear as completed is not enough; you then need to process them, maybe fork them, collect them, etc..  If you want to do this in general, Akka Streams (follow links from [here](http://akka.io/docs/)) are nearing 1.0 and will facilitate the production of complex graphs of parallel processing.

Comment: Excellent - thanks! Is there a corresponding solution for multiprocessing or is this only about multithreading?

Comment: If I join two `.par.map.` in a series, will the second one start working the moment the first one produces something? E.g. if I do this: `someWorkQ.par.map(x => f1(x)).par.map(x => f2(x))` will the first `map` wait until all results are computed before "feeding" the second one, or do they run asynchronously together? In plain words, will `f2` be called on the first successful result of `f1` the moment it becomes available or will it wait until all elements of `someWorkQ` are processed by `f1`?

Comment: @ttsiodras - You don't need to repeat the `par`.  Whether you do or not, however, it will wait for the first map to be completely done you get to the second.  So you would need to `someWork.par.map{ x => val y = f1(x); f2(y) }`, and then you would enforce that `f2` happens right after `f1`.  If you want something more complex, Akka Streams are made for that.  (Handles the linear case well, but also more complex cases of branching and merging.)

Answer (score 0):

There is both a Futures api that allows you to run work-units on a thread pool (docs: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html) and a "parallell collections api" that you can use to perform parallell operations on collections: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html